# Changing store locator marker

Tags: wordpress

I am using the WordPress store locator plugin.

It is showing stores with a marker in a map. How do I change that marker image with my own created image?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create your own marker image and replace it with the original one.

Please follow [this](https://wpstorelocator.co/document/use-custom-markers/).

This is a very simple technique shown there with the WordPress Store Locator plugin to change the marker image.

Comment: Is it possible to change it based on category/tag ?